# How to append select list in a php contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to append the selected html item on the form to be sent along with the email. I would like to know how to correctly fetch the value from the select list and pass it to PHP. I have not been able to correctly figure it out. I would appreciate any assistance. Below is my code...

```
    function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("contact-submit").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
    formdata.append( "t", _("t").value );
    formdata.append( "w", _("w").value );
    formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "contact.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("contact-form").innerHTML = '<h2 class="tnx">Thanks '+_("n").value+', we will be in touch soon!</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("contact-submit").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="cat-select">
                    <label class="cat-selects" for="subject"><span>Area of Interest</span>
                            <select name="subject" class="select-field" id="s">
                            <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
                            <option value="Elderly Care">Elderly Care</option>
                            <option value="Child Care">Child Care</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                </div>
```

PHP

```
     <?php
    if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['w']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
        $n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
        $e = $_POST['e'];
        $t = $_POST['t'];
        $w = $_POST['w'];

        $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
        $to = "hello@gmail.com";    
        $from = $e;
        $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
        $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$s.' '.$m.'</p>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Not really sure what your issue is or what you're trying to do. I don't see your code referencing the select box anywhere?

Comment: I would like to know how to correctly add the select box in the php and Javascript file @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "add the select box". Tried copy/paste? Or are you talking about getting the selected value and pass it to your PHP code? You _really_ need to rewrite your question and clarify what you're trying to do, what the actual issue is and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yea I probably didn't write my question well. I would like to know how to correctly fetch the value from the select list and pass it to PHP. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You're already passing other form elements. Have you tried doing it the same way?

Comment: Yes, I was successful with the other elements. But the the select list item doesn't seem to work. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` of your `<select>` element is "s" but your Javascript isn't referencing it anywhere. Assuming your `_()` function refers to the `id`, you will need to add the following line with the similar lines.

```
formdata.append( "s", _("s").value );
```

This should make `$_POST['s']` available for you to use on the PHP side.

Remember to do something to escape *all* the fields sent through this form, not just the text inputs and textareas, to avoid any attempts to exploit the site or the recipient of the email.